# How to Download Multiple files from a index page table using PHP?

Tags: php, mysql, download

[image]

from these indexed links(eg: C00001125) i Just want to download some files at once, is there any way? Please Help.

Answer (score 0):

```
My existing code is
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "root1";
$dbname = "impdborg_test";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "SELECT id FROM test";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
       echo '<td><a href="uploads/'.$row["id"].'.3d.mol">'.$row['id'].'</a><br><br></td>';
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();
?>
```